# Private class variable with default value - syntax error

Tags: php, oop

Could anybody tell me what i am doing wrong. Wanted to declare my class with some private variables with default values but i got syntax error while declaring $current_week_day and in each attempt of declaring 'name' and 'date' property.

```
class Catwz_Shortcode{
    private $add_script=false;

    private $current_week_day=date('w')==0 ? 7 : date('w');
    private $week_days=array(
        '1'=>array(
            'name'=>__('Monday', 'codeaddict-task'),
            'date'=>date('Y-m-d',time()+(1-$this->current_week_day)*24*3600),
        ),
        '2'=>array(
            'name'=>__('Tuesday', 'codeaddict-task'),
            'date'=>date('Y-m-d',time()+(2-$this->current_week_day)*24*3600),
        ),
        '3'=>array(
            'name'=>__('Wednesday', 'codeaddict-task'),
            'date'=>date('Y-m-d',time()+(3-$this->current_week_day)*24*3600),
        ),
        '4'=>array(
            'name'=>__('Thursday', 'codeaddict-task'),
            'date'=>date('Y-m-d',time()+(4-$this->current_week_day)*24*3600),
        ),
        '5'=>array(
            'name'=>__('Friday', 'codeaddict-task'),
            'date'=>date('Y-m-d',time()+(5-$this->current_week_day)*24*3600),
        ),
        '6'=>array(
            'name'=>__('Saturday', 'codeaddict-task'),
            'date'=>date('Y-m-d',time()+(6-$this->current_week_day)*24*3600),
        ),
        '7'=>array(
            'name'=>__('Sunday', 'codeaddict-task'),
            'date'=>date('Y-m-d',time()+(7-$this->current_week_day)*24*3600),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: You can't use expressions in class variable definitions in PHP < 5.6. Put it in your construct.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect ;)